# Loosing data with nodejs + totaljs + heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, total.js

I have a problem with a recent deployment as I am loosing data.

I made demo users with login information and it worked for a few hours late in the night.  When I woke up this morning, most of the users are missing and the posts I made as the admin are gone.    Is there a name for this type of data loss?

My guess it's due to how I set up the node application on Heroku.

To my understanding the heroku server goes to sleep and it looses data since the application is server and client side.

Is this correct?

If so, how do I go about fixing this?

I am using Total.js premium messenger.   What is the best way to deploy a node app?

thanks,
(self taught newbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I recommend to use own VPS** (e.g. https://www.hetzner.de or https://www.digitalocean.com). [**Total.js Messenger**](https://www.totaljs.com/messenger/) uses NoSQL embedded database and I'll prepare a connector to synchronize data between NoSQL embedded and MongoDB without changing code (coming soon).

Thank you!

Comment: Wow.  Thanks Peter!  Amazing products and the customer service is on multiple platforms!